# I can't setText to navigation view menu item after user is logged it. Error : NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-navigationview

**I'm trying to setText and setDrawable in the NavigationView menuItem after the user is signed in. But after user is signing in i'm getting NullPointerException for the TextView and CircleImageView. Here is the java code and XML for the menu and NavigationView**

```
    @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            userAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
        }
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        userAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        sideMenu = findViewById(R.id.navMenu);

        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
                    updateActivity(true);
                else
                    updateActivity(false);
            }
        };

    private void updateActivity(Boolean isActive) {
            CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView) sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profile_image);
            if(isActive)
            {
                Glide.with(Home.this)
                        .load(Objects.requireNonNull(userAuth.getCurrentUser()).getPhotoUrl())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(circleImageView);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.navName)).setText(userAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);
                sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(false);
            }else
            {
                Glide.with(Home.this)
                        .load(R.drawable.splash_logo)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(circleImageView);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.navName)).setText(R.string.app_name);
                sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
                sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(true);
            }

        }
```

**This is the menu (home.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:title="Login" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/report"
            android:title="Report" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/license"
            android:title="Licenses"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/developer"
            android:title="Developer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:title="Contact us" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:title="Logout"
            android:visible="false" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

**This is NavigationView in activity.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/home"
        android:id="@+id/navMenu"/>
```

navigation_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add your menu xml and layout xml

Comment: Where is your `profile_image`, `navName`?

Comment: It is in the navigation_header. I've added the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to get `headerView` from NavigationView and then get your `CircleImageView` and `TextView` like below:

```
View headerView = sideMenu.getHeaderView(0);
CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
TextView navName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.navName);
```

**Complete solution:**

```
private void updateActivity(Boolean isActive) {

    View headerView = sideMenu.getHeaderView(0);

    CircleImageView circleImageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    TextView navName = headerView.findViewById(R.id.navName);

    if(isActive) {
        Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(Objects.requireNonNull(userAuth.getCurrentUser()).getPhotoUrl())
            .centerCrop()
            .into(circleImageView);

        navName.setText(userAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
        sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);
        sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(false);
    } else {
        Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.splash_logo)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(circleImageView);
        navName.setText(R.string.app_name);
        sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
        sideMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this? Please include here

Comment: NullPointerException got solved but I got this new error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity`

Comment: Did you faced this problem due to my changes? Probably not. That is other problem i think

Comment: No. For the first time it worked then I logged out and tried to login again then I got this error